# Access Django Website from another computer on same network

Tags: python, django

As the title says I want to access my django website on a different computer on the same network.

Both are running windows 10 connected to the same network. The host is connect through wifi and the other through ethernet cable.

I've changed the allowed host to my ip address.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['71.89.113.52', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

And ran the the server.

```
(VIRTEN) C:\Users\HP\Desktop\BBTennis\VIRTEN\src>python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But I still can't access it on the other computer. When I go to **71.89.113.52:8000** or **0.0.0.0:8000**, I get the message, This site can't be reached.

If possible, please present an answer with every direction I should take such as how to configure my network settings or django changes I must make.

Comment: 1) check both are on same network , 2 on windows go to cmd and type ipconfig and get IP address,  3) python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 , 4) go to other PC on same network and type IP_Address:8000

Comment: Are you sure you're using the IP address assigned by the router and not the external IP address? If it's assigned by the router most likely it will start with 192.168.**

Comment: Ok so they are on the same network. The main computer's ip is 192.168.1.xxx and the second computer's ip is 192.168.1.x so do I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000? I did and went to the address of the first computer 192.168.1.xxx:8000 and it still said This site can't be reached. What do i do now? Do I add the other IP to allowed host?

Answer (score 6):

1. check both are on same network
2. on PC1 windows go to cmd and type ipconfig and get IP-1 address
3. PC1 : python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
4. go to other PC2 on same network and type IP-1_Address:8000

Comment: Ok so they are on the same network. The main computer's ip is 192.168.1.xxx and the second computer's ip is 192.168.1.x so do I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000? I did and went to the address of the first computer 192.168.1.xxx:8000 and it still said This site can't be reached. What do i do now? Do I add the other IP to allowed host?

Comment: On PC1 You can try with allowed_host = [*]

Comment: what does 0.0.0.0 mean here? I gave different IP as command line arg as 127.1.1.1:8000 but didn't work.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is representation of  Ip address (all IPv4 addresses on the local machine), If a host has two ip addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs., so when we do IP-1_Address:8000 on 2nd machine it connects to server

Comment: @Dr.Essen you have to make sure Ip you are using in 2nd computer is available in allowed_host file in 1st computer where server is running

Comment: @Vaibhav, Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The `71.89.113.52` IP looks like a public ID address. I'd guess your request is going to a DNS outside your network and then being blocked on the way back in by the `:8000` port being closed in your firewall.

I'd suggest using network tools such as `traceroute` or `ipconfig` on your computer to first confirm the IP address of the target computer, and then i'd using `python manage.py runserver x.x.x.x:8000` to start the server. If you can't see your other computer already, then running a django server isn't going to change that.

Comment: the request won't go to DNS if IP address is used to access the server, there is no name-to-IP resolution to be done.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry about that. What I meant was, will a local computer be able to locate another computer on the network directly by its public IP address? I'd have thought the request would go outside the network, perhaps to a server controlled by his internet service provider, and then be routed back.

Comment: No, if the devices are on the same network and share the same network mask then the request is simply forwarded to destination after ARP resolution by the switch, if dst address is found.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. In the case presented in this question, is there some way the network knows which computer is 71.89.113.52? When I've done this before I've just used a local IP directly so didn't have to consider how a public IP would work (I'm assuming 71.89.113.52 is a public IP).

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py`, set

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Then run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now make sure your machine firewall allows incoming and outgoing traffic. I use a Linux machine, so from control center go to firewall and allow both incoming and outgoing traffic.

Finally, on your local network machine, in the browser, type:

```
<<your host pc IP address:8000
```

This is it! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having to use IPv4 address listed at *Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:*, usually there are several adapters listed in ipconfig other that this, like I initially tried using one listed under *Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8* and that request didnot follow through in other device outside of my computer.